# How do I destroy and recreate a graph with tooltips in anti/G6?

Tags: graph, destroy, antv

I create a graph using Antv/G6, and this graph has tooltips. It works properly. However, if I destroy and recreate the graph (see code below), the graph redisplays, but the tooltips are no longer displaying. Any idea would be greatly appreciated as I am currently at a loss for ideas.

```
    if (endpointsGraphCreated) {
            endpointsGraph.destroy();
          }
          endpointsGraph = new G6.Graph(endpointConfiguration); // ERROR
          endpointsGraphCreated = true;
    
          // This element must be mounted before creating the graph
          const data = { nodes: gNodes, edges: gEdges.slice(0) };
          // endpointsGraph.data(data);
          endpointsGraph.read(data); // combines data and render
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was misusing destroy(). I should be using clear() instead and make sure to not recreate the graph. The following works as expected:

```
      if (endpointsGraphCreated) {
        // removes all nodes and edges. Leaves configuration intact
        endpointsGraph.clear();
      } else {
        endpointsGraph = new G6.Graph(endpointConfiguration); // ERROR
        endpointsGraphCreated = true;
      }
```